# How to put HTML text-box form input into Express Route Paramater

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a way for users to search through my mongo database via an endpoint like this:

```
app.get('/search/:input', function(req, res){
  console.log(`get request to: /members/${req.params.input}`);
  var regexValue = '\.*'+req.params.input+'*\.';
  db.collection(myCollection).find({"full_name": {$regex: regexValue, $options: 'i'}}).toArray((err, members) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(members);
    res.render('search/list', {members: members});
  })
});
```

I want them to be able to type in a text box and have it go directly do this endpoint.  I have a very simple text box like this:

```
<form action="/search/">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" ><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My problem is I don't know a clean way to get the submitted string from the text box into the request parameter.

Comment: A form submit is a post submission. Why not app.post() instead of app.get()?

Comment: why you want to pass in params you can use query.

Comment: I don't want to use POST because I am not adding anything to the database, I am just asking for data back: AKA GET.  Thanks Rahul, query params is what I was missing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Express Route `app.get('/search/:input', function(req, res){`  then `:input` is a path paramaters input, but your html form is going to make a GET request `/search/?firstname=firstname_value`, the request will not maching to the Route.

Use `app.get('/search', function(req, res){` instead of your current code, then `console.log(`get request to: /members/${req.query.firstname}`);` if you want to use GET method.

(I don't know why log show `/members/` ??? while route setting is `/search/`)

Comment: Thank you.  Changing from request parameters to query was what was missing!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the inputbox value using ajax get method, access the value using **req.params.input** .Below is the code that I have tried.

**app.js**

```
app.get('/:input', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.input);
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" ><br>
<input type="button" value="search" id="search">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#search').click(function(){
        var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/users/"+firstname,
            method: 'get'
        }).done(function() {

        });
    })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```